# Network Error when viewing contact from Joomla front end

Tags: contacts, joomla, error

I'm looking for some guidance with the following issue:

I have Civicrm setup as a joomla extension. Everything works great, except one minor issue.

When viewing a contact from the joomla frontend, civicrm keeps poping up the following message:
"Network Error
Unable to reach the server. Please refresh this page in your browser and try again."

If I view a contact from the backend(administrator) there's no such issue.

Though the error is being displayed, it doesn't seem like anything is actually broken as everything shows as it should.

No errors are showing in the browser console and I've followed all steps here:
https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,35850.0.html

Joomla 3.4.5 
CIvi 4.6.10
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I apologize if I left out any crucial information.
Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Civi? Which version of Joomla? Do you have the CiviDiscount extension enabled?

Comment: What do you mean by "viewing a contact"?  Is this a link from a profile that lists contacts, or is it from something else?  Generally speaking, you shouldn't be able to view backend CiviCRM pages from the Joomla frontend.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response.

@ Joe McLaughlin
Joomla  3.4.5
CIvi 4.6.10
No Civi discount extention.

@Andrew Hunt
By contact, I mean a client profile. 
For example: I search for a contact by name. Open their profile, the profile seems to display just fine, but still gives network error.

Comment: Thanks, would be good to update the original question with version numbers, always useful.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that something is misconfigured in your site.  From the frontend, you should only be able to go to "front-facing" pages, such as contribution pages, event forms, and profile forms (and I mean [CiviCRM profiles](http://gitbook.civicrm.org/organising-your-data/profiles.html), not the contact records themselves with the tabs and all).  Most importantly, contact search should not be available unless you have a profile with searchable fields configured, and you would most likely want to restrict those results to a group.

Comment: I'm probably going to have a hard time explaining this. I apologize in advance

I have civicrm setup with Joomla on an intranet site. Joomla is using LDAP to authenticate users. Only users in a specific active directory group can see the Joomla page.

@Andrew Hunt
I have advanced search, and add new contact forms front facing. So certain employees can access the database and add, search and edit contacts, without having access to the backend functions (they're linked to from the joomla front end menu..

Comment: Here's an example of the links I have setup:

Add Contact:
?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/contact/add&ct=Individual&reset=1

Search for Contacts:
?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/contact/search/advanced&reset=1

View All contacts:
?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/contact/search&force=1&qfKey=0&reset=1

This is the link when editing a contact (and where the network error shows)
index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/contact/view&reset=1&cid=599&key=c8759658e93a31a9236bf73117575ed0_5257&context=search

Comment: Yeah all of those features should only theoretically work from the back end.  I'm not surprised that they sort of work but then fail in certain circumstances.  This is the sort of thing that works well in Drupal because there is no division between front end and back end; in Joomla, CiviCRM is back-end only with those exceptions I mentioned.